# NoSuchElementException using driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'list-card-heading') in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, classname, nosuchelementexception, findelement

For the below line of code:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'list-card-heading')
```

I am getting below error:

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [23], in <cell line: 1>()
1 driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'list-card-heading')
```

Initially I had :

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('list-card-heading')
```

but did some modifications in code by adding this below two lines:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'list-card-heading')
```

I was expecting to get below results:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="945ae2a8da0536bea44330c4bbf0b24e", element="581cbcf9-7bb9-40dd-8601-4109cad55272")
```

But got this error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".list-card-heading"}
```

Is it the driver issue? or selenium library issue.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('list-card-heading')
```

in [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3) is equivalent to:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'list-card-heading')
```

using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4)

Possibly the AUT(Application Under Test) changed or is a dynamic element, the reason you see the error.

---

### This usecase

To identify a ***visible*** element ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "list-card-heading")))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: when I put this- element=

I am getting TimeoutException-chk below:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [12], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "list-card-heading")))

File ~\anaconda3\inst\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:80, in WebDriverWait.until(self, method, message)
     78     if time.time() > end_time:
     79         break

Answer (score 0):

A `NoSuchElementException` is thrown when the webdriver cannot find an elements that use the locator strategy it has been given.

While sometimes this happens because of a legitimately bad xpath, in my experience, this often happens because of a dom timing issue, and this can be caused by a variety of things, either in your code, or on the website's side of things.

## Solution

I recommend using a `WebDriverWait` to make sure an element exists before using attempting to interact with it. Here is an example of what that might look like:

```
//Declare your driver as you normally would
WebDriverWait wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(len(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'list-card-heading')) != 0)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'list-card-heading')
```